# numpy Polynomial to vector

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

How do I extract the coefficient vector from a `numpy` polynomial?

In Python, when using the `numpy` package to construct a polynomial, how do I extract the coefficients of this polynomial as a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numpy` package has 2 classes of polynomial, the *deprecated* `poly1d` and the recommended `Polynomial`.

Let's start with a vector that will become the source of the coefficients of our polynomial:

```py
v = [5, 18, -5]
```

We can construct a `Polynomial`-class object:

```py
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
p = Polynomial(v)
```

we can now obtain the coefficient vector again using `coef`

```py
p.coef
```

Which gives:

```py
array([ 5., 18., -5.])
```

The method for the deprecated `poly1d` class objects is the same (`coef`), but you would use `poly1d` instead of `Polynomial` to construct the polynial (which is not recommended anymore, you should use `Polynomial`).